# UI will be blocked while using async and await in c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, ui-thread

Here I need to export some data from a local server into Excel. I am using an `async` call for that method. But still, it is blocking the UI while exporting the data.

May I know the reason why the UI is being blocking?

Also, I need some clarification

> 1)`await` keyword is using to wait some time until the process is
>   completed, then what is the **difference b/w synchronous and
>   asynchronous process**.
>
> 2)If one method is declared as `Async` task, then all inner methods
>   are performing as asynchronous?
>
> 3)While Executing inner methods(method1,method2,method3), method3 will
>   be depends upon method1. So, put `await` keyword for method1. Am I
>   right?

Code snippet:

```
private async void ConvertExcel(object sender)
{
    var excelEngine = new ExcelEngine();
    var application = excelEngine.Excel;
    var newbookWorkbook = application.Workbooks.Create(1);
    var work = newbookWorkbook.Worksheets[0];
    var openDialog = new SaveFileDialog
    {
        FilterIndex = 2,
        Filter = "Excel 97 to 2003 Files(*.xls)|*.xls|Excel 2007 to 2013 Files(*.xlsx)|*.xlsx"
    };
    if (openDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        newbookWorkbook.Version = openDialog.FilterIndex == 1 ? ExcelVersion.Excel97to2003 : ExcelVersion.Excel2013;
    }
    else
        return;
    try
    {            
         // This method is used to get the data from server.          
         var table =  GetFullDataAsync();
         work.ImportDataTable(table, true, 1, 1, true);
         using (Stream stream = openDialog.OpenFile())
         {
            newbookWorkbook.SaveAs(stream);
         }

         newbookWorkbook.Close();
         excelEngine.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Exception message: {0}",ex.Message);
    }
}

internal async Task<DataTable> GetFullDataAsync()
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataTable = GetDataFromServer(DataEngine.Query,DataEngine.Connection);

    dataTable.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    return dataTable;
}        


public DataTable GetDataFromServer(string query, DbConnection connection)
{
    if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        connection.Open();
    }

    var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = query; 
    command.Connection = connection;

    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    var dataTable = new DataTable
    {
        Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    };
    dataTable.Load(reader);
    return dataTable;
}
```

Comment: Your  `async` method doesn't `await` anything. Also return type from an `async` method should be `Task`.

Comment: Your method isn't async at all, since it doesn't actually do anything related to tasks or similar. Just adding `async` doesn't magically make it async, you also need to use `await` and tasks.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) await keyword is using for wait some time until the process is completed, then what is the difference b/w synchronous and asynchronous process.

synchronous: waiting blocks the thread, so locks the ui
asynchronous: waiting frees up the thread, so does not block the ui

> 2) If one method is declared as Async task, then all inner methods are performing as asynchronous?

Don't assume that is true.  You probably want that to be the case, but it is up to you as the developer to code it that way.
The complier does not enforce this for you.

In your code above, the answer is no; your code is not asynchronous.  Notice that you never use the `await` keyword.
You could need to access the data in an asynchronous way first (returning a Task), otherwise async/await keywords can't help you.

> 3) While Executing inner methods(method1,method2,method3), method3 will be depends upon method1. So, put await keyword for method1. Am i right?

Yes.  If each method is returning a Task, then await them all.
Typically when you starting using await in one place, it will bubble up through the rest of your code, so you keep adding more awaits as you have descibed.

Comment: If i put await it will be wait for complete that operation.So it will act as like synchronous.Then what is the difference between  before await and after await?

Comment: In your specific case, no difference. `await` only really works with code which is already asynchronous.  It doesn't magically make your database call change from synchronous to asynchronous.  You want to find an asynchronous DB call  (e.g.`command.ExecuteReaderAsync()`)

Comment: The best way to say thanks is with an upvote and/or accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

```
GetFullDataAsync().ContinueWith((table)=>{
      work.ImportDataTable(table, true, 1, 1, true);
         using (Stream stream = openDialog.OpenFile())
         {
            newbookWorkbook.SaveAs(stream);
         }

         newbookWorkbook.Close();
         excelEngine.Dispose();
})
```

Comment: Hi @lzikon, I also try with this one. Same problem is occurred.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code to use async communication with Sql server like that:

```
private async Task ConvertExcel(object sender)
{
    var excelEngine = new ExcelEngine();
    var application = excelEngine.Excel;
    var newbookWorkbook = application.Workbooks.Create(1);
    var work = newbookWorkbook.Worksheets[0];
    var openDialog = new SaveFileDialog
    {
        FilterIndex = 2,
        Filter = "Excel 97 to 2003 Files(*.xls)|*.xls|Excel 2007 to 2013 Files(*.xlsx)|*.xlsx"
    };
    if (openDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        newbookWorkbook.Version = openDialog.FilterIndex == 1 ? ExcelVersion.Excel97to2003 : ExcelVersion.Excel2013;
    }
    else
        return;
    try
    {            
         // This method is used to get the data from server.          
         var table = await GetFullDataAsync();
         work.ImportDataTable(table, true, 1, 1, true);

         var saveWorkbookTask = Task.Run(() => {
             using (Stream stream = openDialog.OpenFile())
             {
                newbookWorkbook.SaveAs(stream);
             }
         });

         await saveWorkbookTask;

         newbookWorkbook.Close();
         excelEngine.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Exception message: {0}",ex.Message);
    }
}

internal async Task<DataTable> GetFullDataAsync()
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataTable = await GetDataFromServer(DataEngine.Query,DataEngine.Connection);

    dataTable.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
    return dataTable;
}        


public async Task<DataTable> GetDataFromServer(string query, DbConnection connection)
{
    if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        connection.Open();
    }

    var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = query; 
    command.Connection = connection;

    var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();

    var loadTableTask = Task.Run(() => {
        var dataTable = new DataTable
        {
            Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
        };
        dataTable.Load(reader);
        return dataTable;
    });

    return await loadTableTask;
}
```

But you still have blocking IO operations. So if your file is large than the UI will be blocked when the file will be written to disk.

Comment: Hi @michael, i have more than 50,000 thousand records in sql server. Is the reason for blocking UI?

Comment: Your initial code blocked the executing thread when running SQL query and writing a file to disk. I have made the SQL server operation async, but loading data to a `DataTable` and writing new file to disk still run synchronously. You can run this operations in separate threads to prevent your UI from freezing.

Comment: Check [Task.Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Run_System_Func_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__) method which allows to create a task from the thread.

Comment: But the UI will be freezed, before execute below lines loading data to a **DataTable** and writing new file to disk.

Comment: what kind of application do you have? is it a WinForms desktop app?

Comment: Yes it is winforms desktop app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159683/discussion-between-michael-and-pandi).